# Address validation with partial address information (ZIP only)

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, customer-address

I need to add the ZIP field on the sign-up page.

I enabled the `setShowAddressFields` parameter in order to show address fields, then I overrode the file `/template/persistent/register.phtml` to show only the ZIP field.

Of course, the address validation fails and so I googled for the solution, but I only found some indication to modify the DB and the Zend validation function. I don't want do that, because I need address fields required during the checkout process.

So, any idea to simply show and store the ZIP field?

Comment: https://amasty.com/customer-attributes.html

Comment: too expensive! I just need to show the ZIP field in the the signup page.

Comment: http://magento4u.wordpress.com/2011/03/28/add-extra-fields-in-registration-page/

Answer (score 1):

Please create `local.xml` in your theme layout folder.

Refer the code below in `local.xml`:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <customer_account_create> 
      <reference name="customer_form_register">   
        <action method="setShowAddressFields">
          <param>true</param></action>    
      </reference>
    </customer_account_create>

</layout>
```

or

In customer.xml (current theme layout), add the below code in `customer_account_create` node:

```
<action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
```

so it look like

```
<reference name="content">          
    <block type="customer/form_register" name="customer_form_register" template="customer/form/register.phtml">
       <action method="setShowAddressFields"><value>true</value></action>
       <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="customer.form.register.fields.before" as="form_fields_before" translate="label">
             <label>Form Fields Before</label>
        </block>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Clear the cache after added code.

Please find the `_basicCheck` function in `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract`, this validating the registration required fields, so you have to rewrite this function `_basicCheck`.

Please refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970628/magento-1-4-2-make-registration-fields-not-required) its for telephone field (customize for zipcode field), have a look on this. Hope this will helps

Comment: thank you, but as I wrote in my question, I've already enabled the setShowAddressFields parameter. it works, but I need just the ZIP field, not the entire Address section.

Comment: yeah you customize the `register.phtml`(just copy from base theme to your current theme template folder)

Comment: Already done, but it doesn't work because the others address fields are still required. I've to override Zend Validation, but I don't want to do it

Comment: Please refer the edited part above, hope that will helps

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::validate()`
you will find this little gem:

```
if (empty($errors) || $this->getShouldIgnoreValidation()) {
            return true;
        }
```

so, if your pre-set `ShouldIgnoreValidation` flag on the address object (billing and shipping), address validation will always result true.

However, if you do set that, you'd also not get any validation of the ZIP (or any address fields you may have as required) You would have to craft your own validation somewhere else.

Customer address data save is initiated in `Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Customer::_afterSave

```
/**
     * Save customer addresses and set default addresses in attributes backend
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $customer
     * @return Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract
     */
    protected function _afterSave(Varien_Object $customer)
    {
        $this->_saveAddresses($customer);
        return parent::_afterSave($customer);
    }
```

so you would most likely be able to use the _beforeSave event to inject the flag to the address objects. (not tested)

Alternatively, rewrite the method `Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::validate()` and place your own logic to skip validation when it is to be skipped.

Hope that at least helps you along.
Good luck